# Autoencoder for Dimensionality Reduction - varying result - parameter tuning

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction

I'm not an expert in autoencoders or neural networks by any means, so forgive me if this is a silly question. The problem and steps taken to solve problem are as follows:

- There exists a data set with **5200** rows and **113** features from industrial sensors [Numeric Type].
- The task is to use Autoencoder for the *unsupervised dimensionality reduction* purpose.
- The goal is to gain a result with 3 features so as to plot the data for visiualization and further machine learning models input.
- The overall construction of Autoencoder is as:

---

- Preprocessing step using minmax scaling:

```py
train_scaled = minmax_scale(clean_Data_numeric, axis = 0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=train_scaled)
df.head()
```

- Splitting the data set:

```py
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(train_scaled, train_size = 0.8, random_state = seed(2017))
```

- Constructing the Autoencoder:

```py
ncol = train_scaled.shape[1]
encoding_dim = 3
input_dim = Input(shape = (ncol, ))

# Encoder Layers
encoded1 = Dense(40, activation = 'relu')(input_dim)
encoded2 = Dense(20, activation = 'relu')(encoded1)
encoded13 = Dense(encoding_dim, activation = 'relu')(encoded2)

# Decoder Layers
decoded1 = Dense(20, activation = 'relu')(encoded13)
decoded2 = Dense(40, activation = 'relu')(decoded1)
decoded13 = Dense(ncol, activation = 'sigmoid')(decoded2)

# Combine Encoder and Deocder layers
autoencoder = Model(inputs = input_dim, outputs = decoded13)

# Compile the Model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

- Autoencoder summary:

```
Model: "model_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_14 (InputLayer)        (None, 113)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_112 (Dense)            (None, 40)                4560      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_113 (Dense)            (None, 20)                820       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_114 (Dense)            (None, 3)                 63        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_115 (Dense)            (None, 20)                80        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_116 (Dense)            (None, 40)                840       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_117 (Dense)            (None, 113)               4633      
=================================================================
Total params: 10,996
Trainable params: 10,996
Non-trainable params: 0
```

- Fitting:

```py
autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train, nb_epoch = 5, batch_size = 32, shuffle = False, validation_data = (X_test, X_test))
```

- Evaluation:

```py
encoder = Model(inputs = input_dim, outputs = encoded13)
encoded_input = Input(shape = (encoding_dim, ))
encoded_train = pd.DataFrame(encoder.predict(train_scaled))
encoded_train = encoded_train.add_prefix('feature_')
print(encoded_train.shape)
encoded_train.head()

-------------------------------------
(5287, 3)

    feature_0   feature_1   feature_2
0   0.021782    11.836038   1.777279
1   0.018666    11.803829   1.770958
2   0.000000    11.711332   1.765472
3   0.025804    11.797852   1.765566
4   0.001563    11.896879   1.787951
```

Now, The problem is each time I run the autoencoder with different setting like

- nb_epoch = 5, batch_size = 32, shuffle = False
- nb_epoch = 10, batch_size = 64, shuffle = True

I will get totally different result for 3 features, and in case of plotting the features, The total shape of 3D points are different each time of running. Thus,

- How can I be certain that I am using right parameter and setting for my autoencoder?
- Which parameter should be used for this setting which be ended up in accurate 3D representation of points by 3 features?

Thank You

Comment: What makes you think that the data can be meaningfully represented well in 3 dimensions? When the input has 113 dimensions?

Comment: What are the tasks you want to do on the dimensionality reduced data? Finding groups (clustering)? Finding odd data (anomaly detection)? Detecting particular events? You might be best off using the end-task to evaluate your dimensionality reduction technique

Comment: @jonnor: Thank for your comment. In fact, the only way to plot the data so as to acquire a sense of visual representation for this data set which comes from industrial sensors was to implement a dimensional reduction in my  mind. Do you know any other methods to visualize this data set while being meaningful as well?

Comment: @jonnor: The purpose of this task is to implement unsupervised anomaly detection to find local outliers.

Comment: Then I would recommend just learning the autoencoder end-2-end, using the reconstruction error as the anomaly score. And not treat it as a separate feature extraction tool. Then you do not have to limit the output to a very constrained 3 dimensions, but instead have maybe 8-64. For interpretability consider instead something like Shapley values or LIME. Or for visualizations, consider UMAP/TSNE to 2d on the latent space feature vector.

Comment: Is this a time-series btw?